# Programmatically create SQL Server CE 4.0 Database and add a schema in C#?

Tags: c#, schema, sql-server-ce, database-schema

I'm having a go at learning to use SQL Server CE databases as a storage medium for my applications. I've currently been storing data in text and xml files, but thought I should move onto something more appropriate for my project as the text files are getting abit messy.

I have now learnt how to programmatically create an SQL Server CE 4.0 database file in C#, but is there any way to programmatically add an already built Schema to that newly created database file in C#?

Comment: @Guvante yes you're right, I will delete my comment.

Comment: That question is not a duplicate, this one asks for schema and doesn't even reference dynamic creation of the final file. (Re-added comment for others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it depends on what approach you use to work with a database. If Linq to Sql is available (say, you're not using .Net Compact Framework), you can create database by the following code:

```
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext("Data Source=\"test.sdf\""))
{
    dc.CreateDatabase();
}
```

instead of

```
SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source=\"test.sdf\"");
en.CreateDatabase();
```

Linq DataContext creates db schema automatically.